# How to create on mouse over dropdown menu in drupal 7?

Tags: 7

Am working on drupal 7.x and using pixture reloaded sub theme 2.x. Under the Main Menu, am creating a menu with the menu name "Development". On mover over the menu "Development", in drop drop, list of sub-menus should list out. I installed a nice-menu module, but i don't know how to use. Please give a step by step tutorial to create a sub menu on mover over. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use nice menu or super fish menu
nice menu will create two blocks called nice menu 1 and nice menu 2 you have to choose on of them as a block and in configuration you will choose a menu to display

also superfish module will create 4 blocks (it is a dynamic number form config menu) and give you more options to style your menu also option to choose which menu you want to display